# Schedule a service for execute every half hour

Tags: android, android-service

I've write a code for launch a service each half hour when my app is closed:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, serviceIntent, 0);
alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pIntent);
```

Where BackGround service extends IntentService, download some data from a server, and if some conditions are verifyed, show a notification on notification bar.

But it happen that service is executed immediatly when i close my app, and not after half hour.
How can i correct my code for make first execution after half hour?

Comment: Check out `SyncAdapter` here: http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html . As long as you declare your service in the manifest, you'll be able to launch it from your sync adapter which can be scheduled to run periodically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it happen that service is executed immediatly when i close my app, and not after half hour.

The second parameter to `setInexactRepeating()` is when you want the event to first occur. When using `ELAPSED_REALTIME` or `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`, that needs to be expressed as `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+...`, where `...` is how far from now (`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`) you want the event to occur in milliseconds. Your code does not do this; your desired start time is in the past.